# Terraform backend.tf via modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I've modules in another directory. So I want to add the backend.tf and set the provider data from linux environment variable .

But terraform giving error .

My Structure is showing as below .

```
main.tf
└── vpc
├── backend.tf
├── export.sh
├── vars.tf
└── vpc.tf

## main.tf
module "my_vpc" {
      source = "../../vpc"
      instance_tenancy = "default"

}

## backend.tf
terraform {
backend "s3" {
        region = "${var.aws_region}"
        bucket = "${var.TERRAFORM_BUCKET}-vpc"
        profile = "${var.ORGANISATION}"
        key    = "${var.ORGANISATION}"

    }
 }

 provider aws {

    profile = "${var.ORGANISATION}"
    region = "${var.aws_region}"
 }
```

I've exported variables ORGANISATION,REGION and TERRAFORM_BUCKET variables from terminal , but it give this error :

```
   Error: module "my_vpc": missing required argument "aws_region"

   Error: module "my_vpc": missing required argument "TERRAFORM_BUCKET"

   Error: module "my_vpc": missing required argument "ORGANISATION"
```

How Can I solve this issue ?

Notice :  call backend.tf from module via environment variables . (Dynamic and default variables )

Please Help !

Comment: Define your variables as "export TF_VAR_aws_region=us-east-1" that will get recognized properly.

Answer (score 2):

The value for variables in a Terraform script can be provided a couple of different ways.

[Input Variable Configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html)

- Via a `.tfvars` file => [Variable files](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-files)
- Via command line
- Via environment variables => [Environment Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables)

Since you are trying to provide them via environment variables, you should following the naming patter required.

```
$ TF_VAR_terraform_bucket=bucket_name
$ TF_VAR_organisation=org_name
```

Then when you perform `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` terraform will load the variables.

If you don't have the `aws_region` variable defined as an environment variable, then you will need to put it in a `.tfvars` file and use `terraform plan -var-file config.tfvars` or pass it in via the command line using `terraform plan -var us-east-1`.

This is all assuming that in your vars.tf file you have the variables defined.

```
variable "organisation" {
   type = "string"
}
variable "terraform_bucket" {
   type = "string"
}
variable "aws_region" {
   type = "string"
}
```

*** Edit 1

Thinking through your question, if the variables are needed inside the module then you will need to update your call to the module to include those variables in the use of it.

I cannot tell by the formating of your structure if the `backend.tf`, `vars.tf` and `vpc.tf` are inside the `vpc` folder or not.

```
module "my_vpc" {
   source = "../../vpc"
   instance_tenancy = "default"
   bucket = "${var.TERRAFORM_BUCKET}-vpc"
   profile = "${var.ORGANISATION}"
   key    = "${var.ORGANISATION}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html) say about variables in backend config.

> Only one backend may be specified and the configuration may not
>   contain interpolations. Terraform will validate this

This might help - [#17288](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17288)